# Sistema de login en php no funciona (Checkear si email y usuario existe)

Tags: php

Ahora el problema es que `if( !count($results) )` esto no funciona, se salta al else directamente.
El codigo completo es este, gracias :).

```
<?php
require 'database.php';
    if (!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password']) && ($granted=="true")) {
        require 'database.php';
        $message = 'Ha ocurrido un error';
        $sql2= 'select id from users where email=\''. htmlentities($_POST['email'], ENT_QUOTES). '\''; 
        $records = $conn->prepare($sql2);
        $results = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if( !count($results) ) {
            $message = '';
            if (!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO users (email, password, user) VALUES (:email, :password, :user)";
                $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
                $stmt->bindParam(':user', $_POST['user']);
            }
            if($_POST['password']==$_POST['confirm_password']) {
                $password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
                $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password);
            } else {
                $error = 'password';
            }   
            if ($stmt->execute()) {
                $message = 'Successfully created new user';
            } else {
                if($error=="password"){
                    $message = 'Credentials does not match';
            } else {
                $message = 'Sorry there must have been an issue creating your account';
            }
            }
        } else {
            $error = 'exist';
            $message = 'Account alredy exist';
        }
    } else {
        $message = 'No tienes permisos para realizar está acción.';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Proba cambiar `if( !count($results) )` por `if(count($results) === 0 )`. Saludos

Comment: Me parece que el fetch tendrías que hacerlo después del execute

Comment: Hay un `prepare` y un `fetch` pero nunca ejecutas la consulta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como comenta AlfaBravo, te falta ejecutar la consulta. Además estás intentando validar un booleano, y es correcto, lo incorrecto es que intentes validarlo con el `count()` de por medio. Te cambié el nombre a las variables para que tuviera más sentido lo que estás haciendo.

[Documentación fetch()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php)

Saludos

```
$sql2= 'select id from users where email=\''. htmlentities($_POST['email'], ENT_QUOTES). '\''; 
$stmt= $conn->prepare($sql2);
$stmt->execute();

$data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
if( $data ) {
   ...
} else {
  echo 'No hay registros o falló la consulta';
}
```

Answer (score -3):

estas colocando mal el result debe ser results

```
$row_count = $results->num_rows;
```

Comment: Está utilizando el driver `PDO`, no `mysqli`